# How to filter and get array by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
const id = [1, 4, 10]
const data =[{id: 1, name: Banana}, {id: 2, name: Mango}, {id: 3, name: Chili}, {id: 4, name: WaterMelon},  {id: 10, name: WaterMelon}]
```

I tried filter It's showing me empty value. I want to remove matched by id in an array.

Comment: Show what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `filter` out matched ID, try this code:

```
const result = data.filter(({id}) => ids.indexOf(id) < 0);
```

```js
const ids = [1, 4, 10]
const data =[{id: 1, name: 'Banana'}, {id: 2, name: 'Mango'}, {id: 3, name: 'Chili'}, {id: 4, name: 'WaterMelon'},  {id: 10, name: 'WaterMelon'}];

const result = data.filter(({id}) => ids.indexOf(id) < 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const result = data.filter(({id}) => !ids.includes(id));
```

---

**Full snippet:**

```js
const ids = [1, 4, 10];
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Banana'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Mango'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Chili'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'WaterMelon'
}, {
  id: 10,
  name: 'WaterMelon'
}];

const result = data.filter(({id}) => !ids.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am sorry. I want to remove matched by id.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const result=data.filter((value)=>!id.includes(value.id))
```

Comment: It would be helpful to other users if you elaborate on your answer and give explanation

Answer (score 0):

using `filter` it will select the ids of data,
and your object name type data should be string or maybe you want it as a variable so you will not get error.

```
data.filter((object) => !id.includes(object.id))
```